# xmpp syncing mechanism for iOS client

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, xmppframework

I have been using iOS client https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework
successfully install ejabberd on client side and enable the archive mode on server, able to send and receive message.

My problem is how to get older messages and sync to my local core-data. I have read the framework support and it partially support XEP-0136.

I will able to make any custom APIs from server to fetch the messages and sync on the local.
But i did not get any common message id or so on that basis i will sync.

If anyone has idea about syncing. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

hi i have done many thing in xmpp from (http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/) tutorial you can get example from bellow github links you can get many help from that

(demo links: )
https://github.com/sesharim/ios-jabber-client

https://github.com/funkyboy/Building-a-Jabber-client-for-iOS

(xmmp Project demo Link:)

https://github.com/chrisballinger/ChatSecure-iOS

i hope it will help full you..

you can get how to fetch old messages and user list and other detail from that above demo programs.

Comment: i have tried all the three demo projects but no one is providing the history of last messages when the client logout and login.

Comment: @mayank-baddi you can get  that code from the "ChatSecure-iOS" for how to save message to core data that Class name is "XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage" you can find that code from above project than your core data save that and after you can get from code data .. there is no back up facility  at server side message backup in xmpp.

Comment: I have enabled the message archive mode on server, when user deleted the app and install again, I want to get the last messages from server and sync with local, is above code can provide that?

Comment: nope thats code not available in that... sorry dude.

Comment: Hello mitul,  i am getting xmppmessagearchivingstorage as nil so m unable to store message in coredata. can you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Read [XEP-0136](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html) carefully - it describes how to retrieve existing archive.
In fact, XMPPFramework already implement storing all plain incoming messages - you just need to initialize `XMPPMessageArchiving` with `XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage` and activate module on your `XMPPStream`. Then you may perform core data fetch requests on `[XMPPMessageArchiving mainThreadManagedObjectContext]`. If you want to retrieve previously archived messages - you should extend XMPPFramework a bit:

- send  [<list ... /> query](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#manage-list), optionally limited with [Result Set Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0059.html) parameters (which is supported by XMPPFramework too)
- process result (which gives you archived collections by user jid and timestamp) and ask for interested collection with [<retrieve ... />](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#manage-retrieve) query
- process result and send `[XMPPMessageArchiving archiveMessage:]` with each message in result set, and XMPPFramework will do the rest job - inserts in core data storage - for you.

Comment: <list> query is working fine but <retrieve> query is not working, it always return error code-503, service not implemented. Let me know if you have any further idea or some demo code.

Comment: as I rememeber, ejabberd's mod_archive module outdated and not supported, there are maybe bugs. Try openfire and/or prosody, maybe there are better implementations